# Redirecting in IAsyncResult BeginExecute base controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to check authenticated of user login and redirect to controller involve.

How to Code to redirect in this block? Or have any other solution for this situation?

Sorry about my english.

```
<!-- language-all: c# -->
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {            
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name, "Admin"))
                {

                    //if user login is Admin redirect to Admin Controller here
                }

            }
            return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
        }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to redirect to "Admin" control and "Index" action. What is the syntax code? How change requestContext.Url or something like that? Or any other solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin"))
        {
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```